# Set of batch file commands that signs an already compiled DLL?

Tags: .net, assembly-signing

What would be the set of batch file commands that signs an already compiled `.NET DLL`?

The answer to this question should do what is described [here](http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing/).

Comment: Short answer: The commands are in that article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET INSTR_PATH=your.compiled.dll
SET SNK_FILE=your.key.snk

SET IL_PATH=%INSTR_PATH%.il
SET SIGNED_PATH=%INSTR_PATH%.signed.dll

ildasm "%INSTR_PATH%" /out:"%IL_PATH%"
ilasm "%IL_PATH%" /dll /key="%SNK_FILE%" /output="%SIGNED_PATH%"
```

Comment: How could you use command prompt parameters for the two vars at the top?

Comment: To specify INSTR_PATH and SNK_FILE parameters from command line, use %1 and %2 variables: SET INSTR_PATH=%1 SET SNK_FILE=%2

Comment: it's two different tools. ildasm = IL DisASseMbler, ilasm = IL ASseMbler; so first it disassembles DLL to IL code, when assembles it back to DLL